# Can we check convergence of a improper integral with Absolute Convergence series test?

Tags: improper-integrals

I can't write the function properly, so I use MS Word and pasting picture:
[image: screen shot]

Comment: this is not correct

Comment: I highly recommend you first learn a bit of mathjax -- easiest way (for me) is to find a question with the formatting you want and then right click it -- you'll see an option called "Show Math As ->" then click "TeX commands".   Also there is a tutorial here: https://www.mathjax.org/\

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + please [type your formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 2):

I think the trick here is to think of the integral as a series.

If we define
$$
a_n = \int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} \frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}}\, dx \quad \text{for} \ n\in\mathbb{N},
$$
we can rewrite the integral in terms of a series as follows:
$$
\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}}\, dx = \int_{1}^{\pi} \frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}}\, dx + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n.
$$

The first term in this expression is finite, so we need only concern ourselves with the convergence of the sum.

From the definition of the $a_n$'s it is clear that (I leave it to you to actually show this)

- $a_n \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.
- $a_n$ has alternating signs
- $|a_{n+1}| < |a_n|$

Since the three above criteria hold, we can use the alternating series test to deduce that the sum converges. It follows that the integral converges as well.

Comment: I'm allergic to integration by parts

Comment: Thank you, it helps me a lot to understand this problem